# How to compare binary signals with different lengths

Tags: discrete-signals

I have bunch of 1d arrays of 0 and 1 with specific length as data. also i have a key signal(another 0,1 array) with shorter length than my data arrays.
Now how can i have a good measure of similarity or dissimilarity between those long arrays with the shorter key array?

Comment: The operation you are looking for is called the Cross Correlation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation).  It will yield you a new vectors with peaks where the 2 arrays are similars.

Comment: Matlab implementation is called "xcorr". Numpy implementation is called "numpy.correlate"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to elaborate on what you mean by similarity because there are many possibilities.

If you key sequence is embedded in any of your test sequences, the cross correlation is as was suggested by one of the commentators is a good approach, which forms a point by point product between the test and key sequence and sums the results of the product and provides a number, which if the key has $n$ ones the sum of products equal to $n$ indicates an exact match.  The key sequence is shifted relative to the test and the sum of products is calculated for all possible shifts.  This also works for situations where there are error bits in the tested sequence, when the sum product is near $n$.

One might presume that a sum product equal to zero is an indication of dissimilarity, and could be depending on your application but it is usually preferable that measures of similarity should be invariant under information preserving transformations of the data. The replacement of each one by a zero is an information preserving transformation, so a cross correlation value near zero in this case should be considered to be very similar.

A reverse ordering of test sequences is another information preserving transformations.

It is usual to consider dissimilarity as a situation where  a one in the reference would correspond to either a one or zero in the other. In this case dissimilarity to equivalent to statistical independence.

It is sometimes useful to transform $(0,1)$ to $(-1,1)$ when calculating cross correlation.

You can also compare sequences by the ratio of ones to zeros. Run length statistics are also useful.

Cross correlation is compatible with statistical hypothesis testing and confidence bounds. These calculations are covered in any good calculus level statistics text book (like Bhattacharyya and Johnson)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. for more elaboration: the binary key sequence is supposed to be in data sequences but usually it's not! so i'm looking for a way to find out which data sequence need less bit changes to include the key. the thing is data sequences are longer than key. x-correlation seems ok, but what about `Dynamic time warping` ?

Comment: I never tell anyone to not try things, particularly when it’s easy, but DTW is a solution to a specific type of problem where there is some sort of time stretching characteristic associated with the signal and you haven’t mentioned anything to indicate that sort of characteristic. DTW is also considerably more computationally demanding while xcorr on binary sequences is something that people could do in the 1950’s

Comment: While easy to implement, I wasn't happy with the results I got from *DTW* (performance is also an issue). Using a simple *interpolation-decimation* technique in combination with some scaling/averaging is likely to produce better results (at least in my experience). If your signals are of the same length, then you can even skip the *interpolation-decimation step*